# to what was "ionic platform add android" command renamed to?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am starting to learn Ionic, and on building my first application, when typing the

```
# ionic platform add android
```

it says that the command has been renamed. My question is, what was it changed with?

In the tutorial I follow, it says to execute the commands

```
# ionic platform add android
# ionic build android
# ionic run android
```

On searching the web, I have come across the command

```
# ionic cordova run android
```

and it also said that cordova was moved to a CLI which also has to be installed.

But what about "add" and "build"? They are not required anymore?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `ionic cordova platform add android`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are using latest Ionic version, 3.6.0 and above. Since then Ionic cli commands have renamed from 
`ionic platform add android` to `ionic cordova platform add android`

For all the commands append `cordova` after `ionic` keyword.

For list of command, refer to the documentation here at https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/

Your tutorial commands are outdated. But you can still follow them, but just append `cordova` after `ionic` keyword

`ionic platform add android` becomes `ionic cordova platform add android`

`ionic build android` becomes `ionic cordova build android`

`ionic run android` becomes `ionic cordova run android`

"But what about "add" and "build"? They are not required anymore?" - You still need them for adding platforms/plugins.

`add` is used for adding platforms/plugins. For ex: To add ios platform you use `ionic cordova platform add ios`

`build` is used for `Build (prepare + compile) an Ionic project for a given platform`. For ex: To build ios you need `ionic cordova build ios`

`Note:` you can replace ios with android or vise versa in any of the above commands.

Since you started learning check this website out, might be a good place to start - https://ionicacademy.com/

Answer (score 1):

Now "ionic" is renamed with "ionic cordova".

So use:

## ionic cordova platform add android

## ionic cordova run android

***for run on windows****

## ionic cordova platform add browser

## ionic serve